# Как изменить названия log файла в screen

Tags: linux, debian, unix, gnu-screen

Как изменить название log файла при запуске:

```
screen -L
```

Comment: `man screen` отвечает на ваш вопрос. `-c` имя конфигурационного файла в котором может быть команда logfile. остается только попробовать и убедится так ли это

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15026184/4827341 2. http://serverfault.com/q/248193/292034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**дополнение от 20170119**

в [новой версии 4.5.0](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/ChangeLog?h=v.4.5.0) добавили возможность прямого указания имени файла с логами — опцию `-L`:

> Version 4.5.0 (10/12/2016):
>     * Allow specifying logfile's name via command line parameter '-L'

---

имя файла, в который сохраняется лог, устанавливается директивой `logfile` в конфигурационном файле (по умолчанию — `~/.screenrc`, но его можно переопределить либо через опцию `-c путь/к/конф/файлу`, либо через переменную окружения `SCREEENRC`).

по умолчанию значение директивы `logfile` — это `screenlog.%n`, где `%n` — это номер окна (*window*). создаваемые внутри одной сессии окна нумеруются последовательно, начиная с нуля.

лог-файлы не перезаписываются, а дополняются новой информацией.

---

если вы хотите, чтобы для каждой сессии создавался свой уникальный лог-файл, то можно в имени лог-файла использовать не только `%n`, но и другие спец-символы. например:

- `%S` — имя сессии
- `%c` — текущее время в 24-часовом формате `HH:MM`
- `%s` — секунды
- и т.п., подробнее смотрите в секции [*string escapes*](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes) в `man screen` или `info screen string escapes`

---

например, добавьте в `~/.screenrc` строку

```
logfile myscreenlog.%Y%m%d.%c:%s.%n
```

и тогда в текущем (на момент запуска программы *screen*) каталоге получите лог-файлы с такими примерно именами:

- `myscreenlog.20160719.15:11:39.0` — для первого окна
- `myscreenlog.20160719.15:12:02.1` — для второго окна

---

разумеется, можно указать и не относительный путь к лог-файлам, а абсолютный (каталог, естественно, должен существовать на момент запуска программы *screen*).

---

дополнительная информация:

- [Is it possible to name the 'screen' logfile from the -L flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15026184/4827341)
- [Specifying a log name for screen output without relying on .screenrc](https://serverfault.com/q/248193/292034)