# Как сохранять логи приложения? Mono / Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, логирование, mono, gnu-screen

Привет. Запускаю консольные приложения (C# .Net 4.5) через Mono на Ubuntu. Все это дело крутится в screen. Работает! Но в какое-то рандомное время отваливается одна сессия в screen'e. Хочу узнать почему так и не могу найти логи запущенных приложений через Mono. Как сделать так, чтобы каждое приложение, допустим запущенное так: "mono /var/www/test/mybott.exe username password" могло оставлять где-нибудь логи в файлах 1log.txt и т.д...

Comment: фактически дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545945/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто. После команды добавьте знак "больше" (стрелка вправо) `>` и после него адрес куда вы хотите сохранить лог. Например:

```
mono /var/www/test/mybott.exe username password > /путь/к/файлу/log.txt
```

В домашней директории:

```
mono /var/www/test/mybott.exe username password > log.txt
```

Comment: Дело в том, что файлы пустые =)

Comment: Помогло установлением логов через Screen. Но все равно спасибо =)