# Как записать все debug log-и команды 'screen' в один txt файл в Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, embedded

Привет, помогите пожалуйста.
Тестирую IOT проект, необходимо проанализировать debug логи с устройства, которое работает по BLE с мобильным устройством. 
Подключаю  устройство к MacOS по USB кабелю и через кодманду screen вывожу логи с подключенного устройства, однако все записи (подробные, а их много)теряются и не отображаются по завершению процесса. 
Пробовала >> и > и echo - результат один, сохраненный файл пуст

*Команду screen запускаю со старта процесса записи и передачи данных с устройства мобильному приложению, нужны логи самого процесса, а я вижу только результат, что началось с такой команды и пару строк инфы в конце

---

команда для Terminal для записи в txt документ: script log.txt

Comment: Стоп, приведи пример как ты запускаешь `screen`. И так, на всякий случай, вопрос почему выбрана команда `screen`, по каким соображениям?

Comment: [log может записывать программа screen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546263/178576)

Comment: Команду Screen подсказал разработчик, особенности не узнавала.

Answer (score 0):

Когда нужен только лог, без интерактива в Линуксе это делается так. Надеюсь в Маке есть такие утилиты.

Установим скорость на порту:

```
stty -F /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0 \
  speed 57600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

А потом запустим копирование лога в файл:

```
dd if=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0 \
  of=/home/eri/log.txt
```

Переводим в фон по Ctrl+Z и `bg` а потом смотрим вывод через

```
 tail -f /home/eri/log.txt
```

Вывод будет валиться блоками. Размер блоков можно задать параметром к `dd`, например: `dd bs=1 if=.... of=...`

Comment: пс. stty на маке сломан) ставь скорость после открытия dd

Comment: К чему такие сложности, когда сессию можно сохранить? Запускаешь `picocom` из-под монитора сессии, который запишет и вывод, и все действия пользователя на консоли. В brew наверняка всё есть.